# Como criar lista de letras em ordem alfabética no PHP de acordo com número da variável

Tags: php, for

Preciso criar uma lista de letras em ordem alfabética, de acordo com a variável $nalternativas, por exemplo:

```
$alternativas = 3;
aí preciso criar:
a
b
c
```

Se $nalternativas for 2, aí será só a, b, e por aí vai

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a quantidade de alternativas que precisa for inferior as letras do alfabeto, consegue faze-lo à custa da função [`range`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php). Esta função devolve um array com todos os elementos que vão de um elemento inicial a um elemento final definidos como parâmetros da função.

Imaginando que queria 3 alternativas de forma fixa poderia fazer assim:

```
$alternativas = range('a', 'c');
```

Se a quantidade de alternativas é dinamica pode utilizar também [`chr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chr.php) e [`ord`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ord.php) para construir o elemento final dinamicamente. Com o `ord` obtem o valor *ASCII* da letra inicial, depois aumenta a quantidade desejada e obtem a letra resultante desse numero com `chr`:

```
$quantidade = 10;
$alternativas = range('a', chr(ord('a') + $quantidade));
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
    [4] => e
    [5] => f
    [6] => g
    [7] => h
    [8] => i
    [9] => j
    [10] => k
)
```

[Veja estes pequenos exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/AeW4Si)

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro terá que ter um `array` com todas as letras, exemplo:

```
 $letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
```

Após isso, basta realizar um `for` para percorrer o `array` de letras.

Ficaria assim:

```
<?php
    $alternativas = 2;
    $letras = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    if(count($letras) >= $alternativas) { 
        for($n = 0; $n <= $alternativas - 1 ; $n++) {       
            echo $letras[$n];
        }
    }
?>
```

Como o primeiro index de um array é sempre 0, precisei subtrair `1` no laço `for` para poder pegar todos os index corretamente.

Com esse código, obtive a seguinte saída:

`ab`

Se eu não tivesse subtraído -1, a saída seria:

`abc`

Answer (score -1):

Espero que isso resolva sua questão:

```
function alternatives($num){

    $letters = array();

    $last = ord('z');

    $letter = ord('a');

    $limit = $letter + $num;

    for($letter = ord('a'); $letter < $limit; $letter++):

        $current = chr($letter);

        $letters[] = $current;

    endfor;

    return implode('<br>', $letters);

}

echo alternatives(3);
```